# unable to get data from input field,checkboxes and store it in localStorage

Tags: javascript

unable to get data from input field,checkboxes and store it in localStorage. Please let me know how i can debug it. here is the codepen
http://codepen.io/coden/pen/vKaAAv
and JS code is

```
function User(name, email) {
  this.name = name;
  this.email = email;
  this.tesla = tesla.checked;
  this.leaf = leaf.checked;
  this.bmw = bmw.checked;
};

var user_name = event.target.user_name.value
var newUser = new User(user_name, user_email);


function getUserData() {
  event.preventDefault ();
  var user_name = event.target.user_name.value
  var user_email = event.target.user_email.value;
  var newUser = new User(user_name, user_email);
  console.log (newUser);
  localStorage.setItem('userProfile', JSON.stringify(newUser));
}
var personInfo = document.getElementById('personinfo')
personInfo.addEventListener ("submit", getUserData);
```

Comment: have you check by putting "debugger" inside of function